# AD error while executing EXE

Tags: active-directory, remoting, powershell-remoting

Using a PowerShell script (part of script `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $n -FilePath $filepath -Credential ($Cred) -EnableNetworkAccess`) to perform activities like unzip files and run EXE on remote VM.

I'm able to perform activities like extracting and calling EXE first part of the exe activities like DB creation… However, part of the EXE like installing frontend is not working where as exe might validating user in admin group.
Please note that user has admin group/access in both the machines.

**Error message:**

```
</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, String identityValue)
at DataLabsXC.ManagementLib.Collections.XCUsers.ListUsers(String DomainName, String GroupName, String orgUnits)
at DataLabsXC.ManagementLib.XCSqlManager.AddGroups(XCSecGroups SecGroups, String DomainName, String ADAdmin, String ADPassword, Boolean LdapProvider, String OrganizationalUnits)
at DataLabsXC.Management.Setup.FrontEndInstaller.Execute()
at DataLabsXC.Management.BatchProcess.BatchProcessor.Install()
</StackTrace>
<CallingMethod>An operations error occurred.
```

The same script is working fine when executed directly on the targegeted VM instead of being calling from remote machine.

Comment: The error is not a PowerShell error. Show what exactly you're running and how you're running it.

Comment: Following PS script i am using for calling install_Test.ps1 on remotely     $filepath = "C:\Folder\Install_Test.ps1"
$uid = "Abcd\user1"
$pwd = 'Passsword'
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($uid,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -AsPlainText -Force))

$n= "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX"
 If(Test-WSMan -ComputerName $n -EA 0)

    {     Invoke-Command -ComputerName $n -FilePath $filepath -Credential ($Cred) -EnableNetworkAccess  }

Comment: ----------  Remote Script having EXE as $exe = "C:\Fldr\Installer.exe"
$arg1 = "install" 
$arg2 = "C:\fldr1\fldr2"
$arg3 = "C:\\fldr1\fldr2\Config.xml"  &$exe $arg1 $arg2 $arg3              This exe having 3 parts, first two part executing properly, last part is throwing above error.

Comment: Please edit your question. The information is unreadable as a comment.